# Allowing javascript access to server side variables, MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, variables, server-side

I've looked at other kinda similar requests but those didn't help.  My issue here should be easy as I'm trying to set some variables retrieved within a server side group that's within a MVC 4 view.

```
@{
var warningTimeout = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarningTimeout"];
var logoutTimeout = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoutTimeout"];        }
```

I can see the valid values when I step into the code.  Now I need to set these server side values to some js variables, like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">                   
    $(function () {
        var warning = @(warningTimeout);
        var timeout = @(logoutTimeout);  });
```

There's more code besides this in the client side method (like correct closing tags, etc.), but what am I missing here?   Visual Studio 2012 shows a `syntax error` on the `;` at the end of the variable declaration. I also put the `AppSettings` code directly within the `@()` too, but that wasn't cool either.  Thoughts?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio's Javascript error doesn't know how to handle embedded Razor code.
This will work fine at runtime.

However, if the variables are strings, you need to Javascript-escape them.